# mongodb update where argument exists

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, updates

```js
db.filmes.insertMany(
[
  {
    "num": 1,
    "title": "movie1",
    "category": "Horror",
    "review": 5,
    "cast": {
      "director": "R1",
      "artist": "A1"
    },
    "exibition": [
      "Lisboa",
      "Porto",
      "Braga"
    ]
  },
  {
    "num": 2,
    "title": "movie2",
    "category": "Action",
    "review": 3,
    "cast": {
      "director": "R2",
      "artist": "A2"
    },
    "exibition": [
      "Lisboa",
      "Porto"
    ]
  },
  {
    "num": 3,
    "title": "movie3",
    "category": "Animation",
    "review": 3,
    "cast": {
      "director": "R2",
      "artist": "A2"
    },
    "exibition": [
      "Lisboa",
      "Porto",
      "Viseu"
    ]
  },
  {
    "num": 4,
    "title": "movie4",
    "category": "Animation",
    "review": 6,
    "cast": {
      "director": "R1",
      "artist": "A4"
    },
    "exibition": [
      "Lisboa",
      "Porto",
      "Braga"
    ]
  },
  {
    "num": 5,
    "title": "movie5",
    "category": "Horror",
    "review": 5,
    "cast": {
      "director": "R3",
      "artist": "A3"
    },
    "exibition": [
      "Lisboa",
      "Porto"
    ]
  }
]);
```

I need to update all the reviews to 10 where artist "A3" appears?

I already tried :

```js
db.movies.updateMany({cast:{artist:"A3"}},{$set:{review:10}})
db.movies.update({artist:"A3"},{$ste:{review:10}});
```

and other that I cant remember,

there's is a way to do it ?

Comment: Try [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_9Qk0pJqDO_)
On your driver do it with UpdateMany like this   
`db.collection.updateMany({"cast.artist": "A3"},{$set: {review: 10}})`

Comment: thanks , but i doesnt work.... {
  "acknowledged": true,
  "insertedId": null,
  "matchedCount": 0,
  "modifiedCount": 0,
  "upsertedCount": 0
}

Comment: Review your command. most likely a typo. It should work.

Comment: @Takis_ thank you again

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit thank you